# Perl : Set read timeout in client socket

Tags: perl, sockets

I have created tcp client socket , after creating socket the connection got established with 
server . Then I am reading the content from server . In this case. I need to wait only for 10 seconds in read . If the nothing is read . It has to return in specified timeout. what is the way...?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using the standard [IO::Socket](http://p3rl.org/IO%3a%3aSocket) module (though there are older ways), you call the timeout method to set your timeout to 10 before reading.

Answer (score 1):

[perldoc -f alarm](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html)

> If you want to use [`alarm`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/alarm.html) to time out a system call you need to use an [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)/[`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) pair. You can't rely on the alarm causing the system call to fail with `$!` set to `EINTR` because Perl sets up signal handlers to restart system calls on some systems. Using [`eval`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html)/[`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html) always works, modulo the caveats given in [Signals in perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Signals).
>
> ```
> eval {
>     local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die "alarm\n" }; # NB: \n required
>     alarm $timeout;
>     $nread = sysread SOCKET, $buffer, $size;
>     alarm 0;
> };
> if ($@) {
>     die unless $@ eq "alarm\n";   # propagate unexpected errors
>     # timed out
> }
> else {
>     # didn't
> }
> ```
>
> For more information see [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html).